# Unable to cast object of type 'MyService.EndpointConfig' to type 'NServiceBus.Host.IConfigureThisEndpoint'

Tags: nservicebus

I have a problem with NServiceBus: I have defined an endpoint config that implements `IConfigureThisEndpoint`, but when I run the service with a generic host, it complains that the type cannot be cast to the namespace. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, there are *two* namespaces called `IConfigureEndpoint` in NServiceBus. I was using the wrong one - had to reference the ServiceHost EXE instead.

Comment: Dmitri, are you using the trunk (unstable pre-alpha 2.1) or the 2.0 branch (release candidate 2 coming shortly, very stable) ?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me that you have "EndpointConfigurationType" specified in the config file. Can you verify is that is true, if so try to remove it and see if it solves your problem?

Comment: That's ok, I already found the answer - it's due to there being two IConfigureThisEndpoint namespaces in NSB.

Comment: What version are you using? The current trunk have only one interface called IConfigureThisEndpoint.